# Define Declaration in another DLL

Tags: c++, declaration

I have two DLLs. MainDLL.dll and SubDLL.dll.

MainDLL.h

```
void ABC();
void DEF(int iX);
```

MainDLL.cpp

```
void ABC()
{
    DEF(1);
}
```

SubDLL.cpp

```
#include "MainDLL.h"

void DEF(int iX)
{
    printf("Value is: %d", iX);
}
```

My question is how to call DEF declaration like in SubDLL? I don't want to define the declaration in MainDLL.cpp, I want it to be defined in SubDLL.cpp like the example.

Comment: Just that the caller is a DLL doesn't make it nay different from any other external call. Calling an external function from an EXE or a DLL doesn't matter, it's all handled the same.

Comment: So, what do you mean is it is the same method as like this?
SubDLL.cpp

#include "MainDLL.h"

void main()
{
    DEF(1);
}

Comment: There's really no difference between EXE and DLL files, especially in how they use other DLLs. If you can use a DLL from an EXE file, then you can use a DLL from another DLL.